# Users and permissions in CosmosDB with Mongo API

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to have multiple applications access an Azure Cosmos DB datastore with the MongoDB API, but I am having trouble figuring out how to create users and permissions. When trying to create users through the mongo api (db.createUser()) I get `command not supported`. I cannot connect through any of the client libraries for CosmosDB, because they are for the DocumentDB API. Is there any way to use Users and Permissions in combination with the Mongo API for Cosmos DB, or only if I use the DocumentDB API?

Comment: Give it a try using DocumentDB library only. In our experience with Graph API support, we were able to create users using DocumentDB SDK in Cosmos DB accounts with Graph API.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I ended up switching to mongo

Answer (score -2):

You can use the REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-user

or PowerShell:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount
$account = 'MyCosmosDBAccount'
$database = 'MyDatabase'
$resourceGroup = 'MyCosmosDBResourceGroup'
$context = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $account -Database $database -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup
New-CosmosDbUser -Context $context -Id 'newUser'
```

The code sample is from this page:

https://dscottraynsford.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/managing-users-permissions-in-cosmosdb-with-powershell/